# How to remove items from a list A that present in list B (with the removal of duplicates )

Tags: python, list, function

Implement a difference function, which subtracts one list from another and returns the result.

It should remove all values from list **a**, which are present in list **b**.

for example :-

`a = [1,2,3,3,4]`

`b = [7,9,3]`

`the result should be [1,2,4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the result is to use `list comprehension`:

```
a = [1,2,3,3,4]
b = [7,9,3]

c = [x for x in a if not x in b]

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehension will solve it to you:

```
a = [1,2,3,3,4]
b = [7,9,4]
print([item for item in a if item not in b])
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```